# Date validation - Date object differs from input

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I'm working in a script written a few years ago that checks if a date is valid:

```js
//These values are comming from user input
var _day = 19;
var _month = 9; //October (10 - 1 for javascript Date object sake)
var _year = 1986;
var _hour = 0;
var _minute = 0;
var _second = 0;
var result;
    
//Checks if date is valid
var _datetime = new Date(_year, _month, _day, _hour, _minute, _second);
var _valid = 
     _day == _datetime.getDate() 
     && _month == _datetime.getMonth() 
     && _year == _datetime.getFullYear() 
     && _hour == _datetime.getHours() 
     && _minute == _datetime.getMinutes() 
     && _second == _datetime.getSeconds();
     
if(_valid){
  result = 'valid';
}else{
  result = 'invalid';
}

document.write('The date ' + _datetime + ' is ' + result);
```

This date is showing as invalid because `_datetime.getHours()` is returning `1` instead of `0`.

If I change `_day` value to *18* or *20*, the date validates correctly. I just can't see what is wrong.

Comment: This code shows `User input is valid` for me...

Comment: for me also it's showing correct

Comment: Is it a timezone issue?

Comment: I think so @brso05. Also tried with `Date.UTC` here

Comment: `_datetime.getHours() ` is returning `0`

Comment: Note that months are zero indexed, the month is being interpreted as October, not September so your date is a month out, and likely has crossed a daylight saving boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Already considering this when read values from the user input in the full version of the script @RobG

Comment: BTW, running the code produces "valid" for me and the time is 00:00:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a timezone issue, try UTC.

```js
//These values are comming from user input
var _day = 19;
var _month = 9;
var _year = 1986;
var _hour = 0;
var _minute = 0;
var _second = 0;

//Checks if date is valid
var _datetime = new Date(Date.UTC(_year, _month, _day, _hour, _minute, _second));
var _valid = 
    _day == _datetime.getUTCDate() 
    && _month == _datetime.getUTCMonth() 
    && _year == _datetime.getUTCFullYear() 
    && _hour == _datetime.getUTCHours() 
    && _minute == _datetime.getUTCMinutes() 
    && _second == _datetime.getUTCSeconds();


if(_valid){
    console.log('User input is valid');
}else{
    console.log('Invalid date');
}
```

Comment: I tried to fix with `Date.UTC` but forgot to use *getUTC...* functions.  Thank you a lot.

Comment: This proves nothing. The OP treats the values as local, the error in the original code can't be reproduced (I suspect the OP hasn't realised that the date is a month different to that expected). All you've done is show that the UTC methods also work.